# Q) My azure web app restarted. How do I know more about it?

Tags: azure-web-app-service

My azure web app has been restarted intermittently.What would be my best way to investigate this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, you can check the timeline of the Web App being restarted from Azure Portal.

Azure Portal->Home->YourWebApp->Diagnose & Solve ->Availability & Performance Category->Web App restarted->follow the prompts until you see the results.

[image]

You will see the user-initiated events as results by running the logs as above. 
Also, there is a possibility of restart if you have Local Cache enabled at your end. 
If so, we suggest you to, look at swap operations as well as seen below:

[image]

Local Cache helps in  preventing  storage-related web app restarts. However, there can still be conditions where your application can be restarted.
Here, in this case…if you notice that there was a swap operation done to your web app during that time-period, which will result in restart and local cache to warm up on the instance again.

Comment: Thanks for your response Niha.. it worked like a charm :)